# "Magical" number and equations in principle of mathematical analysis

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am currently a freshman in Math major and I'm trying to study Rudin's principle of mathematical analysis during the summer break, but I'm confused about a few things and hope you guys can help me out.

When I was working on the exercises of Chapter 2 and 3, I can always    find some interesting numbers and designs of equations which will    solve the whole proof with relative ease. Sometimes, the logic of the proof makes sense, but how to design those magical equations are    confusing.

For example [Exercise1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhNLU.jpg)
In this case, delta = min(sqrt(2-x^2 / 3), 2-x^2 / (3*abs(x)), in the first paragraph of solution . The design of delta forms a nice and easy inequality in the later proof.

Another example would be:[Exercise2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWJSf.png)
I was focusing on finding the limit of a(n) when n approaches    infinity, and see if it is zero, but the answer key shows such an easy way to solve this. To be honest, I have no clue about how to get such equations, but I love them.

I assume I would meet this type of numbers and equations in the    future as well and I hope I could have the same ability to design    such equations to prove stuff. Is there a specific way to train this    ability? Or is it something that I will be capable of when I was a    senior?

Any help and advice would be much appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: You should try to solve the problem without these tricks. Most of these tricks are unmotivated and unnecessary. In fact such equations are the bane of Rudin's book. Math should not be magical/mystical but enjoyable like any other form of human endeavor.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, It's good to know that this is the bane of the book, thanks god I know this by chapter 3. I will try to prove without thinking about in the future, thanks again

Comment: @ParamanandSingh In fairness to Rudin most of those transformations (or end products of transformations, more precisely) cannot possibly be motivated (in general, there is no way to motivate a backwardly discovered proof; and always explicitly showing this process is out of the question since it can be misleading to some who think every mathematical operation is invertible -- apart from the fact that one should not write textbooks of any size). I agree that they are **sometimes** unnecessary, but how else do you deduce the familiar properties of real numbers from the axioms without these, for

Comment: ...example? I don't think they are the bane of his book as it is a textbook -- thus he has lecturers mostly in mind, not the autodidact. Lecturers can often point out the origin of these tricks, if needed; and the exercises are there for one to discover one's own proofs. Indeed, to actually enjoy such things, one may need to attempt proving them by oneself -- one may chance upon similar constructions if one pursues an indirect method of proof. Therefore, if one knows how to use any well-written book (and I think Rudin's *Principles* satisfies this, by many standards), one can enjoy it well.

Comment: @Allawonder: it's just a personal opinion. I don't like tricks too much. Rather mathematical proofs should be a natural outcome of logical thinking. If there are some very non-obvious tricks then some explanation should be given. As far textbooks are concerned I prefer Apostol's over Rudin's. But I think somehow Rudin's books became a major commercial hit and overshadowed other well written texts.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I see. But it wasn't clear that you were stating a mere opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a specific way to train this ability?

Many would argue that this is what it means to be a mathematician. Most would agree that it constitutes a lot of what mathematicians do.

What I am talking about is the power of constructing your own definitions and proofs. There is no better way to do this than study examples -- especially non-examples, which fail to satisfy some condition of a definition, theorem, etc.; and counterexamples, which show that a statement is false. Another way is to try to design your own examples, usually going the other way as suggested in an exercise (which is usually harder than the routine or suggested way). Then, always try to prove statements by yourself first -- you'll gain much more this way, whether or not you eventually succeed in finding a proof.

Of course, all this will be initially hard as math education at the lower undergraduate level is more of training and exercising than researching and solving problems (and a lot can be said for this, pedagogically), but gradually you will be much more built for what it is mathematicians do and get better at doing these things, and finally at understanding and enjoying mathematics. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable advice, I will keep these in mind, thanks again